# How many attending puppy school are brown and have long hair but are not small?

Tags: combinatorics

Of the 24 dogs attending puppy school
-6 are small
-12 are brown
-15 have long hair
-1 is small and brown and has long hair
-2 are small and brown but their hair is not long
-2 are small and have long hair but they are not brown

I attempted this with venn diagrams but got nowhere.

I have also come across the table method

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      small& brown& long\\
      6&12&15\\
      5&11&14\\
      3&9&14\\
      1&9&12
 \end{array}
\right] $$

Where you started off with 6 small, 12 brown and 15 long hair and then ran through the conditions and subtracted. But I did not understand this method. The answer is 3, but I am more interested in the method used to find the answer. I would like to see as many different approaches to it as possible.

Comment: Hint: you do not need two circles for "small" and "large", etc.  You just need a circle for "small" and large dogs are all those that are not inside that circle.

Comment: Also, just for the sake of it, my first venn diagram which you said had too many sets. is that mainly a problem because it would lead to having something that is unsolvable, or would it simply be a case of having repeated information and therefore taking twice as long to solve, but still arriving at the same answer?

Comment: It is a matter of clutter.  In the original diagram, most of the regions should have no dogs; and you hadn't identified which.  The simpler diagram, with only the eight regions, had no such distractions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have too many sets.   Large dogs are all those which are not in the "small" circle.   They do not need another circle.

Try it with just three overlapping circles "small", "long", "brown".

Comment: Ah yes I got it now thanks.